# Dual boot Windows 7 / Ubuntu 20.04 doesn't find grub.cfg automatically

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2

I had a dual boot installation of Windows 7 and Ubuntu 16.04.  Upon system boot I used to get a Grub screen, which offered dual boot options,as expected.

I erased 16.04 and installed 20.04 in the same partition, without any changes to windows 7.  But now upon boot I get a grub shell.  If I issue 'exit' command, I get to Windows 7 boot manager, and proceed to boot Windows. In order to get to Ubuntu I have to explicitly issue:

> ```
>    grub> configfile (h0,gpr8)/boot/grub/grub.cfg
>    grub> boot
> ```
>
> which gets me to the Grub dual boot screen (albeit with somewhat screwed up graphics), and I can boot Ubuntu.  The output of boot-repair is here: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/gfPjqVqX6f/ , I don't see anything wrong with it.

What am I missing?

Thank you

Comment: You have to be consistent. Your Window & original Ubuntu were UEFI. But then you installed Ubuntu in BIOS boot mode. UEFI & BIOS are not compatible. Only a UEFI install of Ubuntu can boot into your UEFI install of Windows. And if you try to boot UEFI Ubuntu, that is trying to boot UUID of old install so fails. You need to boot in UEFI mode, run advanced mode of Boot-Repair to totally uninstall grub (BIOS version) and install the UEFI version of grub. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI